# NullPointerException creating an AppCompatImageView with mock Context

Tags: android, unit-testing, exception, mockito, android-testing

I am receiving a `NullPointerException` when I try to create an `AppCompatImageView` with a mock `Context` in a test. Doing the same with a normal `ImageView` works.

**This test pass:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertNotNull;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ParallaxViewTest {

    @Mock
    Context mContext;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void initWithContext() throws Exception {
        assertNotNull(mContext);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
//        AppCompatImageView imageView = new AppCompatImageView(mContext);
    }
}
```

**This test DOES NOT pass:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertNotNull;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ParallaxViewTest {

    @Mock
    Context mContext;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void initWithContext() throws Exception {
        assertNotNull(mContext);
//        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        AppCompatImageView imageView = new AppCompatImageView(mContext);
    }
}
```

**And this is the crash report:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.<init>(ResourcesWrapper.java:46)
    at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.<init>(TintResources.java:34)
    at android.support.v7.widget.TintContextWrapper.<init>(TintContextWrapper.java:100)
    at android.support.v7.widget.TintContextWrapper.wrap(TintContextWrapper.java:68)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:60)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:56)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:52)
    at example.views.ParallaxViewTest.initWithContext(ParallaxViewTest.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:68)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:74)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:161)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

**Here the libraries:**

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.18'
```

---

**How can I solve this?**

---

**EDIT**

How can I get a mock `Context` with resources?

This test DOES NOT pass:

```
    @Test
    public void initWithContext() throws Exception {
        assertNotNull(mContext); // PASS
        assertNotNull(mContext.getResources()); // DO NOT PASS
//        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
//        AppCompatImageView imageView = new AppCompatImageView(mContext);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I found the when().thenReturn() functionality. This is exactly was I was searching. Thanks

Comment: You might want to check if that DEEP stubbing might do that automatically; but maybe I am also just getting that feature wrong. Glad you got what you were looking for!

Comment: One final hint: you are over-doing. You are using the Mockito runner already, thus the call to ` MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` isnt required at all. You only need to initMocks() manually when you are **not** using the Mockito runner for some reason. So your "setup" method is actually not required at all (so far; that might change, for example when you want to put some generic when/then clauses into the setup method; because you need them for *all* your tests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you turn to the source code of the class listed in the stack trace ([ResourcesWrapper](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/ResourcesWrapper.java)), you find:

```
public ResourcesWrapper(Resources resources) {
  super(resources.getAssets(), resources.getDisplayMetrics(),
```

And that line 46 is the one with super().

Further looking into the classes in your stack trace, you could come accross:

```
 private TintContextWrapper(@NonNull final Context base) {
  super(base);
  ...
  mResources = new VectorEnabledTintResources(this, base.getResources());
```

So, long story short, yes, you are providing a **non null** mock object to `new AppCompatImageView()` in your code. But then the code you are calling **is calling** methods on that **mocked** object. Sure, that is why you created a mock in the first place. But guess what; by default, the mocking framework will return **null** for any method call.

In other words: you have to understand **which** calls will happen on that mock; so that you can prepare the mock to return something **non null** too!

To be precise: I am not saying that exactly that line from TintContextWrapper() causes this NPE; I am mainly saying: when you give a mocked object into other code, you have to **prepare** that mock to return reasonable results on those method calls that will happen. That could very well mean that you have to create more mocks; so that something like `mockedContext.getResources()` does return a **non-null** result.

In other words: you have to

- identify those calls that happen on that mock object
- then you have to make sure that those calls will return non-null (for example by returning mocked objects again).

Beyond that: more likely, the real answer is to use **Android specific** mocking frameworks. Preparing your mocks to get them "do the right thing" could easily turn into a lot of work.

*Maybe* the simple answer is to use the [**deep stubbing**](https://idodevjobs.wordpress.com/2015/04/09/mockito-deep-stubs-example/) from mockito, by simply writing

```
@Mock (answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
```

But you need to read/try that; I haven't used that myself.

And given your latest: you need to **configure** your mock, like

```
when(context.getResources()).thenReturn(someOtherMock);
```

for example! That is the **whole** point of mocks: you can control what happens when methods are called!

Comment: You're explaining how to search a solution and I appreciate that, thanks, but I think that the answer should be easier because I am using the libraries of Android documentation for test and create a simple AppCompatImageView it shouldn't be hard. ImageView works perfectly, why AppCompatImageView doesn't?

Comment: I assume that I am not the only one with that problem, but following your last comment, the answer is how to set a Resources to the Context, simply.