# Why extends ImageView marked as error?

Tags: android, android-view, android-support-library, android-custom-view, android-context

Android Studio marks as error this line:

```
public class ParallaxView extends ImageView
```

**Here the error:**

```
This custom view should extend android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView instead less... (Ctrl+F1) 

In order to support features such as tinting, the appcompat library will automatically load special appcompat replacements for the builtin widgets.

However, this does not work for your own custom views.  Instead of extending the android.widget classes directly, you should instead extend one of the delegate classes in android.support.v7.widget.AppCompat.
```

It recommends me to extend `AppCompatImageView` but then my JUnit test don't pass because `AppCompatImageView` needs a mock `Context` with resources and `Imageview` doesn't need this.

Here the question to solve the other problem:
[NullPointerException creating an AppCompatImageView with mock Context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42972985/6437300)

**Can I ignore this error and use ImageView? Any other solution?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using `AppCompat` widgets allows you to have some material design (and other new) features on devices with pre-Lollipop versions of Android.

At this point `AppCompatImageView` only provides the support for background tint and vector drawables. If you don't use them, then extending the regular `ImageView` will be fine.

Answer (score 3):

It's not really an error. The app builds successfully right? It's only Android Studio which marks it as error.

You can change this to warning by editing the 'Appcompat Custom Widgets' inspection settings.