# NullPointerException in super class method's constructor when testing using mockito

Tags: java, android, mockito, robolectric

I have a super class:

```
public class A extends Fragment{
    public A(Context context){
        super(context);
    }
}
```

and class B inherits it:

```
public class B extends A{
    public B(Context context){
        super(context);
    }
}
```

In my test class where I'm using Robolectric and Mockito, when I instantiate class B like so: `B b = new B(context)`

I get a nullpointerexception in class A's constructor's super method. Am I doing something wrong?

Here's the test code:

```
@Mock Context context;
@Before
public void setup() {
    initMocks(this);

    B b = new B(context);
}
```

Comment: change the Test Artifact in build variants to Unit test..then run it

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. How do I set the build variant to Unit test?

Comment: Isn't the sample I've provided not enough to understand the problem. If there's something specific you'd like me to add, I'll be happy to.

Comment: @GhostCat I've added it now

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: it isn't that easy.

The exception stack trace which you are hiding from us would tell you/us that those NPE happens within some *base* Android code. Thing is: you are passing a **context** object into the Fragment constructor.

Guess what: the Fragment code then starts **using** that context object. It makes a whole series of calls on that object, in order to retrieve *other* objects, to *then* make calls on those objects.

Right now, you only mocked a Context object. Any calls to it that are supposed to return a value will return **null** by default. Mockito doesn't know anything about the classes you are mocking. So, when you want that a certain call returns something else than null, you have to **specify** that behavior.

So, the "short" answer is: you have to prepare that mock object to be able to be used like this. The long answer ... was already given; and you need to study its [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199000/unit-test-an-android-fragment) in depth!

Beyond that; you can have a look into another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42972985/nullpointerexception-creating-an-appcompatimageview-with-mock-context) dealing with the exact same problem.

Comment: Is the mock object in this case supposed to be the super class?

Comment: You can't mock the super **class**. You mock **objects**. This reads like you are overburdening yourself. Thing is: mocking Android stuff is a whole lot "different" than doing "normal" java unit testing an mocking. Thus: please read that link I provided. Read it until you understand it!

Comment: Um okay. Which object would you want me to mock in this case? It can't be the class under test, and I'm already mocking context.

Comment: I enhanced my answer and added another link to a similar problem. Maybe my other answer there helps more. The point is: you have to check the exception stack trace, and then you have to **mock** all those requests on that context object that will be coming in when super(context) is executed. But I am pretty sure that there are existing frameworks to do that for you. You dont want to go in and re-invent the wheel here.